# LyX: Problem with longtable in landscape

Tags: lyx, longtable, landscape

I am trying to embed a longtable in landscape mode. What I have always done is put `\usepackage{longtable}` and `\usepackage{pdflscape}` in the preamble, then put the table between `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}`. But this is simply not working on the file I have posted at [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1791181/LongtableLandscape.lyx). When I export to pdf, the first page comes out empty, and the second page clips the bottom rows. 
Sorry for this trivial question, but I simply can't figure it out.

Comment: You're not using a `longtable`, but a normal `tabular`, and that cannot break across pages.

Comment: Hi Torbjørn... In LyX I just need to put longtable in the preamble.

Comment: I mean the environment, not the package. Just adding `\usepackage{longtable}` to the preamble does nothing. You have to go into the table settings and activate *Use long table* in the *Longtable* tab. This would also add the package to the preamble, so there's no need to do that manually.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you, thank you. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply adding `\usepackage{longtable}` to the preamble does *not* mean that all tables automatically are allowed to break across pages. The standard LaTeX environment for tables, which is used by LyX as default, is called `tabular`, and does not break across pages. The `longtable` package defines a new table environment by the same name which can break across pages (between table rows). Small LaTeX code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
Default \texttt{tabular}, can not break across pages:

\begin{tabular}{c}
...
\end{tabular}

\texttt{longtable}, can break across pages:

\begin{longtable}{c}
...
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

You have to tell LyX to use the latter construct. This is done in the tabular settings, which is found by right clicking inside the table, and choosing More --> Settings. The third tab is called *Longtable*, and there is a check box *Use long table* at the top that must be checked, see screenshot below. This will also add `\usepackage{longtable}` to the preamble, so it is not necessary to do that manually.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed response, Torbjørn. I just accepted it as correct.