# Add pdf slides to a lyx document?

Tags: lyx, pdf, pdfpages, presentations

I want to add the pdf slides into a lyx document.
That means: for each page in pdf document insert it to the lyx document and seperate it from other slides. I need it for adding notes to lectures.

In Microsoft PowerPoint I can add to each slide notes. I need the same thing in Lyx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Is this a presentation created with `beamer` in LyX, or an externally created PDF?

Comment: it is an externall.

Comment: I shall shamelessly promote my own, but related, answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146920/18228 `:)`

Answer (score 7):

I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve, so there are two parts to this answer.

## `pdfpages`

This technique will let you distribute all the pages of a PDF across as many pages as necessary of a LyX document. I don't know if it's possible to add notes within LyX next to each page/slide, for that purpose the other technique (see below) would be better, though it is more tedious.

1. Insert --> File --> External material, choose the PDF you want to include, and set the template to *PDFPages*

   [image]
2. Go to the second tab, *LaTeX and LyX options*. Say you want to have three slides per page, then you can add the following in the *Option* box:

   ```
   pages=-,nup=1x3,frame,delta=0 1cm,offset=-5cm 0,width=.8\linewidth
   ```

   - `pages=-` says to include all the pages in the PDF.
   - `nup=1x3` says to organize the pages in 1 column and 3 rows per page.
   - `frame` draws a thin black frame around each slide.
   - `delta=0 1cm` adds space between each slide, `0` between columns (there is just one, so none is needed), `1cm` between rows.
   - `offset=-5cm 0` shifts all the slides 5cm to the left (negative x-direction). The default is to place the slides in the middle of the page, this pushes them to the left, making room for notes on the right.
   - `width=.8\linewidth` reduces the size of each slide a little.

The result would look something like this (three pages, with a total of nine slides):

[image]

## Adding a single page from a PDF as a graphic

To add a specific page from a PDF, choose Insert --> Graphics or click the button on the toolbar, as usual when inserting images. Choose your PDF, go to the *LaTeX and LyX options* tab, and add `page=N`, where `N` is the page number, in the LaTeX options box:

[image]

You could for example use a two column ([long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145565/lyx-problem-with-longtable-in-landscape/145616#145616))table or [a pair of minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29474/align-an-image-at-the-right-of-a-text-in-lyx/29489#29489) to add notes next to the image(s).

Comment: the major issue with these two methods though is that lyx showes only the first page in the preview. using clipping becomes a nightmare...

Answer (score 1):

Burst the PDF file into seperate PDFs (one per page) and include them as an image to your document separately. Insert page breaks if needed.

For example, if you have *pdftk* installed, you can run the following command in the terminal:

```
pdftk yourSlides.pdf burst
```

This will create a couple of files "pg_0001.pdf", "pg_0002.pdf", etc., which you can include as images when using pdflatex.

Comment: Why should one spit the PDF into seperate files? LaTeX can easily emebed specific pages of a PDF.

Comment: I am searching for a code that do it.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: In order to allow the OP to use the "insert image" feature of LyX. Inserting specific pages of a PDF file will probably require inserting custom LaTeX commands.

Comment: @Ruedi: I don't do Lyx - you mean Lyx can not embed a specific page of a multi-page pdf?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Yes it can. Rudie: Insert --> Graphics, choose the multipage PDF, under *LaTeX and LyX options* write `page=10` in the LaTeX options box to include the tenth page of the PDF.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ah, looks like that should be the answer. Perhaps the OP will accept it if you write it again as a stand-alone answer.